# Are there C++ style guide metrics of quality?

Tags: c++

I'm in university right now and I'm currently only graded on whether my code is fast enough and outputs correctly. I've gotten to the point where I want to dive in and really internalize a style.

I'm not looking for a list of them or your opinion on them. I'm pretty aware of what's out there. I'm just looking to be able to make a more informed choice.

I know it is largely subjective, but there must also be quantifiable differences between them that I can consider.

The considerations I've thought of are: Industry adoption, intuitiveness, formatting support (plugins for [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text), etc.), and maybe applicability to other languages (that may not make sense though). Am I missing anything that I should consider? What is important in a style?

Comment: I don't think the specifics of a style matter - what matters most is *consistency*: that is, you pick a single style and use it consistently. Nothing makes me cringe like seeing a mixture of 1TBS, tabs vs spaces, and K&R all in the same file - or no consistency in identifier capitalization.

Comment: That's a good point. I have a habit of 'getting ready to learn/do something' than actually just learning/doing something. thanks

Comment: Take a look at the Doxygen web site.  The Doxygen tool will supply you with commands that will help build documentation.

Comment: Readability and Simplicity.  Use meaningful variable and function names.  Code that is readable has less chance for injected defects.

Comment: Are you looking for formatting rules like which braces should start in a new line (which can be reformatted automatically) or naming and notation rules like capitalization, underscores, best practices, e.g. how to pass parameters, C++ class architecture and design or measurable metrics like average line length, amount of comments? - Oh, I see, it is an old question.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [MISRA C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C) and related coding rules. But look also at [GNU coding standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) and [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html)

<sup>(take time to read criticisms too!)</sup>

In practice, you'll learn a lot by studying the source code and contributing to some *existing* [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) project.

Read [The Mythical Man Month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month) and understand that there is [No Sliver Bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet).

<sup>(As commented, consistency matters a lot)</sup>

Comment: Also pay attention to why certain restrictions are specified for a given style, so you know when those restrictions do and don't apply.  For example, the Google style guide says not to use exceptions because most of the code in their open-source stuff uses C error-handling techniques, and thus can't handle exceptions; they aren't saying not to use exceptions ever, just not to use them with code written according to their style guide.

Answer (score 1):

[CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) are a set of guidelines maintained by Bjarne Stroustrup and
Herb Sutter with community suggestions. They are pretty complete and useful. You'll learn a lot from them.

There are coding rules. If you're more focused on formatting, leave it. It's more personal and it's better to follow styles of existing projects if you are contributing to existing ones and formatting does not affect functions of language.